# Simulink/Simscape tag

Tags: discussion, tags

At present there is a [matlab](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab) tag, which in itself is very odd for an electrical/electronics section.

Matlab and an associated tag would naturally reside within Stackoverflow.

Two products that exist alongside Matlab are: Simulink & Simscape. Both, to some degree show some relevance in residing within the electrical stackexchange.

Not only does this stackexchange cover aspects of control & control theory (something simulink & simscape are designed for)  but equally are geared towards electrical analysis

[Simulink Capacitor doesn't load in simulation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/195993)

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/193639

[Schmitt-Trigger with Simulink](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109255)

[PID controller DC motor Design using simulink](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182309)

and more....

All of these have the [matlab](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab) tag when in actual fact they are simulink/simscape

Would a simulink and/or simscape tag be of use? It is afterall a system and electrical circuit simulator... its focus is just a bit more abstract from the likes of LTspice/Tina etc...

Answer (score 2):

Matlab EE questions only fall outside our scope in an extremely strict site definition, which doesn't serve us very well. It's the same with microcontrollers and HDL: the presence of code *by itself* does not mean the question is off-topic. I believe [matlab](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab) should stay, it's not hard to find several examples not using either Simulink or Simscape.

I'm skeptical that a Simulink tag is worth adding (as a subdivision of [matlab](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab)) I'm content to maintain the status quo here.

Comment: Fair enough on keeping the matlab tag. I still think there is merit in a Simulink tag. Simulink is a superset to Matlab (those who know matlab might not have or know simulink). Ok on stateflow as that is a different way of doing a similar thing (physics based not integration based). I was raising the point about a simulink tag because the vast majority of "matlab" tag usage is for Simulink. There are very few matlab only: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164336 & https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/156896 come to mind while SIMULINK/STATEFLOW are quite common